# C++ TCP Server compare strings fails

Tags: c++, linux, string, sockets, networking

I am new to C++ and have decided to learn more about how C++ can utilize sockets. I am currently following this [tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/).

I am trying to compare two strings. One string is a literal, `test`, the other is recieved from the client which is using telnet. However the conditional statement always evaluates to `false` and subsequently the code block never executes. What am I missing?

Here is the code that I am having issues with:

```
while( (read = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {


    std::string a = std::string(client_message);

    std::string b = std::string("test");

    std::cout << "string a" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string b" << b << std::endl;


    if (a == "test")  {
        std::cout << "Strings match!";
    }



        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of a and b? (Ok, b should be "test")

Comment: What is the value of `read`?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam The output of a is "test" as well . This is what is confusing. Is there some kind of hidden special character within one of the strings?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The value of read is 6

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. So use at this point a debugger and verify the characters in a. BTW in the if block there is a std::endl missing. Maybe the block is executed but the output is still in buffer.

Comment: Or you use first this line: std::cout << "string a '" << a << "'" << std::endl;

Comment: @TobiasWollgam The block still isn't executed. I will fire up gdb and see if string a should be what I expect it to be.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a newline at the end of the string, so the actual null-terminated string that is sent is "test\n". Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet will send `CRLF`, which will add two extra bytes to your `client_message` array. You need to trim whitespace from that content before the comparison.

Also, code `std::string b = std::string("test");` is redundant. Just do `std::string b = "test";`, or better yet remove it altogether, since you're not really using it in the comparison anyway.